# How to add to array from list and return array

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I am at an internship and have a problem I have tried to solve for three days, please help.

My problem: I have a list of data and it has to me converted into an array.

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
    {
        foreach (Template template in templates)
        {
            template.ToArray();
        }
        return ();
    }
```

This does not work and I have tried one milion different things, I just can't figure it out.

Template:

In Template:

```
public class Template:IEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
}
```

In ExempelAccess:

```
     public IEnumerable<Template> ListAllTemplates()
    {
        this.session.Query<Template>().ToList();
        return ListAllTemplates();
    }


    public int Create(string templateName, string content)
    {
        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var template = new Template { Content = content, TemplateName = templateName };
            session.Save(template);

            tx.Commit();
            return template.Id;
        }
    }
```

In ExempelEngine:

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
    {
        foreach (Template template in templates)
        {
            template.ToArray();
        }
        return ();
    }
```

Templatesummary:

In IExempelManager:

```
public interface IExempelManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    TemplateSummary[] ListTemplates();
    [OperationContract]
    void Create(string templateName,  string content);
}
 [DataContract]
public class TemplateSummary
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

In ExempelManager:

```
public TemplateSummary[] ListTemplates()
    {

        return ListTemplates();
    }
```

In ClientFactory:

```
public TemplateSummary[] ListTemplates()
    {
        return Channel.ListTemplates();
    }
```

In ExempelViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<TemplateSummary> TemplateSummaryResult { get; set; }
```

In ExempelEngine:

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
    {
        foreach (Template template in templates)
        {
            template.ToArray();
        }
        return ();
    }

        public TemplateSummary[] ListTemplates()
    {

        return ();
    }
```

These are all the references that are in the solution.

Comment: How `Template` and `TemplateSummary` are related?

Comment: How does one convert a `Template` into a `TemplateSummary`?

Comment: Template is an instance of a template with ID, Name and Content. It is not related to TemplateSummary except it needs to be added to the array and returned.

Comment: @FadiY, please update question with definition of `Template` and `TemplateSummary`

Comment: If `Template` and `TemplateSummary` is unrelated at all, how can it be expected that returning `template.ToArray()` will magically transform itself to `TemplateSummary[]`? There must at least be certain relationship between `Template` and `TemplateSummary`

Comment: @FadiY: i'll try to re-phrase. Your input is a sequence of `Template`s. Your output is a sequence of `TemplateSumary`ies. Obviously, `Template`(s) must be converted to `TemplateSummary`(ies) somehow. So, how conversion must be performed?

Comment: TemplateSummary array can contain elements of type TemplateSummary and not Template. That's what @dennis has to say!

Comment: Updated now hope this helps.

Comment: @Fadiy where is definition of `TemplateSummary`?

Comment: @FadiY - No, it doesn't help. You need to explain how `Template` gets converted (or mapped) to `TemplateSummary`?

Comment: I kind of thought the transformation was going to take place in this method.. My "teacher" kind of said I should do it this way.

Comment: @FadiY - We need to know how to turn a single `Template` into a single `TemplateSummary` in order to write the code.

Comment: If you are on an internship, go and ask any senior dev around for help, not here on SO. Otherwise your internship is worthless.

Comment: @Enigmativity I guess that's what I am trying to figure out too. Sorry for the vague question.

Comment: @OndrejTucny I have asked many times but I don't want to ask too many times.

Comment: @FadiY - Asking too many times is better than not enough.

Comment: @FadiY - I'm going to guess if you post the full definitions of `Template` and `TemplateSummary` in your question we can figure it out for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity Okay I will do that, will take some time though

Comment: @Enigmativity Updated!

Comment: @FadiY and what do you want to reach? simple convert from `Template` to `TemplateSummary` or what?

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Yes that's what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943079/how-to-add-to-array-from-list-and-return-array?noredirect=1#comment57619727_34943079) you want to get this method

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
{
    return templates.Select(x => new TemplateSummary 
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            TemplateName = x.TemplateName,
            Content = x.Content
        }).ToArray()
}
```

Do not forget to include `using System.Linq;` at the file head.

Comment: This was exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I can assume that there is a method that summarizes a template - `TemplateSummary SummarizeTemplate(Template template)` - then this is all you need:

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
{
    return templates.Select(t => SummarizeTemplate(t)).ToArray();
}
```

For a more detailed answer you need to explain how `SummarizeTemplate` would work.

---

This is what you need:

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
{
    return templates.Select(t => new TemplateSummary()
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        TemplateName = t.TemplateName,
        Content = t.Content,
    }).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the `ToArray` on `Template` returns `TemplateSummary[]` the problem is resolvable using `SelectMany`

```
TemplateSummary[] TransformTemplates(IEnumerable<Template> templates)
{
    return templates.SelectMany(i => i.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: "Assuming that `ToArray` returns `TemplateSummary[]`" - bad assumption, IMO. The question definitely needs clarification.